# React – Add unique key to array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to add a unique key to the returned elements this function provides.

```
function RowList() {
  const rows = [<Row0 />, <Row1 />, <Row2 />, <Row3 />];
  return (
    <>
      {rows.map(row => (
        <tr key={?}>{row}</tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried:

```
function Rows() {
  const rows = [<Row0 />, <Row1 />, <Row2 />, <Row3 />];
  return (
    <>
      {rows.map(row => (
        <tr key={row}>{row}</tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

But `[object Object]` is returned as the key.

I also **will not** be able to do something like

```
let x = 0
function Rows() {
  const rows = [<Row0 />, <Row1 />, <Row2 />, <Row3 />];
  return (
    <>
      {rows.map(row => (
        <tr key={x = x + 1}>{row}</tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

As I will need to be able to remove and add back to the array later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you can't just do this:

```
// DON'T DO THIS
{rows.map((row, index) => (
  <tr key={index}>{row}</tr>
))}
```

As the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) says, that's a "last resort" and really only useful for static lists. You've said your list won't be static.

It's fairly unusual to have an array of already-created elements like that rather than an array of the *data* for the elements. If you can avoid it, I would, and give the data entries enduring ID values that you can use as keys, e.g. (`name` is obviously a stand-in for actual data):

```
class RowInfo {
  static id = 0;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = RowInfo.id++;
  }
}

function RowList() {
  const rows = [new RowInfo("one"), new RowInfo("two"), new RowInfo("three"), new RowInfo("four")];
  return (
    <>
      {rows.map(({id, name}) => (
        <tr key={id}><Row name={name}/></tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

That assumes that they should all be the same type of component, of course, which may not be true.

If you can't do that and must pre-create the actual elements, I'd probably create wrapper objects:

```
class RowInfo {
   static id = 0;
   constructor(element) {
     this.element = element;
     this.id = RowInfo.id++;
   }
}
function RowList() {
  const rows = [new RowInfo(<Row0 />), new RowInfo(<Row1 />), new RowInfo(<Row2 />), new RowInfo(<Row3 />)];
  return (
    <>
      {rows.map(({id, element}) => (
        <tr key={id}>{element}</tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Or if they don't have any props you need to specify, you can let React keep track of them, as that's part of its job:

```
class RowInfo {
   static id = 0;
   constructor(Comp) {
     this.Comp = Comp;
     this.id = RowInfo.id++;
   }
}
function RowList() {
  const rows = [new RowInfo(Row0), new RowInfo(Row1), new RowInfo(Row2), new RowInfo(Row3)];
  return (
    <>
      {rows.map(({id, Comp}) => (
        <tr key={id}><Comp/></tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a live example of that one:

```js
const Row0 = () => <div>Row 0</div>;
const Row1 = () => <div>Row 1</div>;
const Row2 = () => <div>Row 2</div>;
const Row3 = () => <div>Row 3</div>;

const {Fragment} = React;

class RowInfo {
   static id = 0;
   constructor(Comp) {
     this.Comp = Comp;
     this.id = RowInfo.id++;
   }
}
// Have to use <Fragment></Fragment> in the below instead of <></> because
// Stack Snippet's version of Babel is out of date and
// doesn't understand <></>.
function RowList() {
  const rows = [new RowInfo(Row0), new RowInfo(Row1), new RowInfo(Row2), new RowInfo(Row3)];
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {rows.map(({id, Comp}) => (
        <tr key={id}><Comp/></tr>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<RowList/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Absolutely incredible answers.
Thank you.

Comment: @Neil - No worries! Glad that helped!